# On dual nature of light?

Tags: visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, wave-particle-duality, aether

It is said that light exhibits dual nature, in some instances as particles or photons and other instances as electromagnetic waves. How to detect which nature is light exhibiting and why only one nature exhibited at a time, why can't the be photons moving in wave-like motion? The Michelson-Morley experiment tries to refute the existence of ether but all waves require a medium to propagate?

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon

Comment: *why only one nature exhibited at a time* It is *not* true that light only exhibits one nature at a time. There are many experiments in which it behaves simultaneously as a wave and a particle. Also, this is nothing specific to light -- it's a general thing about quantum mechanics and applies to the wave-particle duality of electrons, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to detect which nature is light exhibiting and why only one nature exhibited at a time,

We perform an experiment and make some observations. We then see whether those observations show wave-like or particle-like behavior of the light involved.

For example, when we see interference or diffraction effects, we call those wave-like behaviors. When we see that only discrete amounts of energy can be absorbed from or emitted into the electomagnetic field we call that a particle-like behavior.

But really, light doesn't sometimes behave like a particle and sometimes behave like a wave. It always behaves like light. It's only that some of the behaviors of light are analogous to the behavior of particles in classical physics and others are analogous to the behavior of waves in classical physics.

> why can't the be photons moving in wave-like motion?

Because we observe behavior (for example diffraction) that isn't consistent with this model.

> all waves require a medium to propagate?

This just isn't true. Many of the waves that pre-1900 physicists were familiar with (for example, sound) propagated through physical media.

But that doesn't mean it's not possible for some other type of wave (light) to propagate without a medium.